# ASP.NET Core asp-for field not in sync with input text field if setting input to empty string

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

How do I set asp-for="TicketDetails.StartDate" = null using JQuery and setting a checkbox to off?

Most of the below code does what I need it to do. However, I have issue when I try to clear startDate. Clicking the checkbox off, JQuery code is suppose to set input-sdate to '' and it does, but when I submit the form, I can see the C# data (asp-for="TicketDetails.StartDate")
is not null or empty. In the submit and post to backend,  I can see that input-sdate is empty but TicketDetails.StartDate maintains it's old value.

For most scenarios the StartDate value is in sync with input-sdate. It's only when I try to clear the date value that it's not in sync.

**Class**

```
namespace MyProject.Classes.Models
{
    public class TicketDetails
    {
        ...

        [Display(Name = "No Start Date")]
        public bool NoStartDate { get; set; } = true;

        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yy}")]
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;

        ...
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div class="col-6">
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="chk-sdate" asp-for="TicketDetails.NoStartDate" checked="@(Model.TicketDetails.NoStartDate)" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row  align-items-left">
        <div class="col-4">
        <label class="custom-control-label" asp-for="TicketDetails.NoStartDate"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control datepick" id="input-sdate" asp-for="TicketDetails.StartDate" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#chk-sdate').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('#input-sdate').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#input-sdate').attr('value', '');
        $('#input-sdate').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: As a work around, in the backend I can just check the value of my checkbox and set a null if needed accordingly.

Comment: You should never trust that client side javascript is working. Your backend absolutely should enforce this type of business rule again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I set asp-for="TicketDetails.StartDate" = null using JQuery and
> setting a checkbox to off? It's only when I try to clear the date
> value that it's not in sync.

Well, based on your shared code you have assigned current date on your StartDate  porperty and your are getting expected because, in MVC application [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#what-is-model-binding) and [model validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#model-state) occurred at the begining which means request firstly goes to the model validator once it meet the condition then it route to the specific controller.

For instance, if you set any annotation on property or assign any value by default that precedence always comes first. In your case you are getting current date while submitting empty value. As you can see below:

[image]

Why This Is Causing:

While you would disable any property it will not be considered anymore on from submit which you can see below:

[image]

Thus, when request has been submitted it will reach to model validator again and took your defined value of current date and controller always will be initialized with defult value.

Solution:

There might be numerous work around which will made the things complex and require more code snippet to write, but easiest solution would be is to modify TicketDetails POCO class defination. Where StartDate property would be initialize as null or string.Empty() and while loading the view, within controller action we would initialize StartDate  value with DateTime.Today it will resolve your issue and you can get null value as expected.

Let's take a look in action:

View Model:

Assuming you have a view Model within that you have attached TicketDetails. So you should modify as following:

```
public class TicketViewModel
    {
        public TicketDetails TicketDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

Model:

```
 public class TicketDetails
    {

        [Display(Name = "No Start Date")]
        public bool NoStartDate { get; set; } = true;

        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yy}")]
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; } = null;

    }
```

**Note:** We even can set string.Empty() or can leave with nothing which will consider DateTime? as default empty value.

Controller Action:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            TicketViewModel ticketViewModel = new TicketViewModel();

            TicketDetails ticketDetails = new TicketDetails();
            ticketDetails.StartDate = DateTime.Today;

            ticketViewModel.TicketDetails = ticketDetails;
            return View(ticketViewModel);
        }
```

Note: Code snippet within view would be as yours and no changes required.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time on your detailed explanation. That makes sense.

Comment: Its pleasure and glad to assist on this.